# How to watch if a query data has changed at any possible time?

Tags: sql-server

I'm building a project where i need to get data from an Oracle remote server from my sql server and i need to create a list with some calculations performed on that data whenever it is refreshed on the remote server.

The objective was to create a SQL Job to run at x time, for example, 4h,8,12,16,20,24,4h,8... everyday to run this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAbastecimentosCalculados
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Abastecimentos TABLE
    (
        Referencia varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        UAP varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        W01 float NOT NULL,
        W02 FLOAT NOT NULL,
        ConsumoDiarioW01 float NOT NULL,
        ConsumoDiarioW02 float NOT NULL,
        Stock float NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO @Abastecimentos
    SELECT * FROM viewAbastecimentosStocks




    SELECT A.Referencia, A.UAP, A.W01, A.W02, A.ConsumoDiarioW01, A.ConsumoDiarioW02, A.Stock, 
        CONVERT(decimal(10,2), ConsumoDiarioW01 / P.NumPAB ) AS ConsumoPAB,  
        CONVERT(decimal(10,2), ConsumoDiarioW01 / P.NumPAB ) * P.QtdMin AS StockMin,  
        CONVERT(decimal(10,2), ConsumoDiarioW01 / P.NumPAB ) * P.QtdMax AS StockMax,
        CONVERT(decimal(10,2), ConsumoDiarioW01 / P.NumPAB ) * P.AlcanceAbastecimento AS QtdAbastecimento
    FROM @Abastecimentos A
    LEFT JOIN UAP U
    ON U.Nome = A.UAP
    LEFT JOIN Parametros P
    ON P.UAPId = U.Id
END
```

However, my client has told me it wants to run it at any possible time. How can I handle this besides adding a manual refresh button?

I thought about using websockets to keep refreshing data on client whenever it is available but that means i have no idea how does it work, like... If i have to run that query every possible second or something like that.

Or is there a way to know when data is refreshed on remote server? Like create a watch on a specific table

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, we have no access on remote server, we can only read data

Comment: You can't watch data on another server no (SQL Server has no watch process anyway, the closest you would have is a trigger which is something that runs upon a specific event, such as an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`). If the Client wants to run the SP at certain points, having a "button" to run the SP does seem like the easiest to implement.

Comment: I suppose this trigger would have to be created on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, the trigger needs to be on the object that is being changed. If it's a DML trigger, then that'll be on a Table/View. DDL would be on the database, Logon, Database creation, etc triggers on the Server. This would be a DML trigger.

Comment: Unfortunately i have no access on remote server besides reading only

Comment: Then the "refresh button" seems the way to go.

Comment: Let's say for example, that we could have this trigger created on remote server by other company. How can i watch changes through it?

Comment: You can't. SQL Server can't watch for changes on an Remote Server, or an event occuring; like I said before.

Comment: Is there a way for Oracle system to simply push data to SQL Server? This way the data is always up-to-date and you can still perform necessary calculation in, say, a trigger.

Comment: The thing is, I'd rather avoid having to duplicate data trying to sync tables. I'm already using openquery doing all the work. The closest to what I can do is a SQL Job to run as often as possible, like every hour every day for example